# Bootstrap 4 Jumbotron content overflows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm implementing a Jumbotron element like this:

```
<div className="jumbotron">
<div>
<h6 className="display-6">Reset Password</h6>
<p className="lead">We've just emailed you password reset instructions at <u>{this.email && this.email}</u></p>
<hr className="my-4" />
</div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the content overflows the jumbotron, like this:

[image]

How do I fix this?

EDIT: Here's another one. The compiled HTML appears like this in my browser:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
         <h6 class="display-6">Activate account</h6>
         <p class="lead"><!-- react-text: 215 -->Please confirm the verification code we've just emailed you at <!-- /react-text --><u>b_kogan@hotmail.com</u></p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Resend email verification code</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, again, it's overflowing:

[image]

Comment: why are using `className` instead of just `class` ? and please post your custom CSS if you have

Comment: I'm using this in a React app, there you use className instead of 'class'. No custom css involved here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example of what you have in your HTML and with using bootstrap 4 and everything looks as expected,I think you have different style applied or this is not the rendered html on the browser.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron">
<div>
<h6 class="display-6">Reset Password</h6>
<p class="lead">We've just emailed you password reset instructions at <u>{this.email && this.email}</u></p>
<hr class="my-4" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep-I had some CSS overriding it in the deployed code, fixed, works now.